# Woocommerce cart total not get updated when selecting option in delivery shipping method

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

In my cart when I select delivery with turf "yes option" I need total get update with main total +200. If I select "no option" total should be updated based on $2 per kg of product weight.

[image: screenshot]

```
if($current_id == 'yes'){ 
    if($total_area>0 && $total_area<=100){ 
        $extra_area_cost = intval(200); 
        $woocommerce->cart->total = $woocommerce->cart->subtotal + $extra_area_cost+ 85; 
    } 
}else if($current_id == 'no'){ 
    $woocommerce->cart->total = $woocommerce->cart->subtotal + $weight_cost +85; 
}
```

Comment: Do you have some code for us to look at, can't do much without it.

Comment: My site link is http://www.greenerlawn.whitehat-staging.com.au/and I have added one product in turf category http://www.greenerlawn.whitehat-staging.com.au/product/platinum-zoysia/

Comment: Requirement is this from client "if delivery is selected another option will be shown. "Do you want this turf to be laid for you?" if yes the price will be 200$ flat rate for quantity under 100 sq. meter and for quantity 100 & above will have 2$ per sq meter price. If turf is not selected the price for other products will be based on weight."

Comment: backend code, can't tell much from this. You must be playing with code in the backend somewhere.

Comment: All code is ready only cart is not updated when these radio button sending values

Comment: if($current_id == 'yes'){

                if($total_area>0 && $total_area<=100){
                    $extra_area_cost = intval(200);               
                    $woocommerce->cart->total =  $woocommerce->cart->subtotal + $extra_area_cost+ 85;                 

                }

            }else if($current_id == 'no'){
                    $woocommerce->cart->total = $woocommerce->cart->subtotal +   $weight_cost +85;
                }

Answer (score 0):

Instead of messing with the woocommerce code, why don't you just set it as a variable product.

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/variable-product/

Then on the product admin page, add attrubute Lay the turf with yes | no
Then create the variables with different prices and weight.

So if you don't want to charge by weight for to lay turf option, just give it no weight.